# How to handle PHP timezone on moving server?

Tags: php, timezone

I've been receiving the usual PHP warnings for using strtotime without setting a default time zone:

> PHP Warning:  date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CST/-6.0/no DST' instead

I read up a lot on what needs to be done, and basically there doesn't seem to be a way around setting a default timezone (either in php.ini as date.timezone = "America/Chicago", or in PHP using date_default_timezone_set('CST6CDT') or similar).

My problem is that we have a moving server that will frequently be in different time zones for demos, so I can't just set a fixed timezone and have everything work wherever we go...

Or can I? There's of course also the possibility that I'm completely misunderstanding the whole timezone concept ;-) Frankly, it's just confusing me more the more I read about ... I also don't know for sure how the server's system time is affected by plugging it into a network in a different time zone - there's just too much I don't know or understand yet (sorry...).

Main reason I want these error messages to stop is that I have to sift through the error logs a lot since this is also my development server, and having to filter all these lines out is just a major pain...

On top of all of that, the application on the server not only uses local times, but it also synchronizes some data with our static server, so I am painfully aware that I'll have to adjust a lot of main server code as well, and for that I can easily force our actual time zone or UTC.

So what's the best option here?

Should I simply hard code UTC in as default time zone, then create a setting in my database and a user interface that we can use to switch time zones and update ALL my code to use all of that, or is there a better and simpler way?

Or should I ignore the whole issue and add @ to every strtotime I use? (*bracing myself for a small riot...*) ;-)

Looking forward to any suggestion...
Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using MySQL for handling dates and using the timestamp column (which stores in UTC and converts back to current timezone)?

Comment: Geeze, you guys are fast ;-) No, I haven't...

Comment: Actually, most of the times I save in MySQL ARE in timestamp format, but that doesn't help me much when I have to display them using date and strtotime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy Jones is correct. Your best bet is to baseline your server completely. What I mean by this is to set all encodings (bash, mysql) to UTF-8 and timezones to UTC. If you do this from the outset, you will save yourself a lot of headache down the road.

With respect to the question you asked, if you store all timestamps in your database as UTC, then you only need to convert based on the end user's timezone. This avoids having to determine if a timezone stored in the database was PST or EST then convert to user's timezone. Plus it allows you to move servers between timezones. For example if you are using VPS across multiple timezones, each of which feeds into the same database, you are ensured that all timezone entries are consistent.

Comment: OK, this makes sense, but I think I misworded something in my question... When I wrote "create a setting in my database", I meant basically a flag that tells PHP into what timezone to convert the timestamp. I didn't meant to save the timezone with each transaction. So sounds like you all are saying that I should default everything to UTC for saving and calculation purposes. But then? Then I'll have to create a small interface to select a current timezone, save that and have all my code use that to convert to while still using UTC as a base - correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. If you provide a GUI for the user to select a timezone, you can store it in your database. When a user logs in, set the timezone as part of the user session, then every time you display a date, pass the users timezone and date to the interface. Also, you could issue the timezone as part of the query and let MySQL do it for you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work for this project, but also like necessary work. And your suggestions here definitely make sense, so thanks so much! I can't always have MySQL do the conversion because I also have other data sources, so it'll be PHP conversion. I take it PHP conversion will automatically detect DST, right? What's the best command that doesn't require extra extensions for the time zone conversion? I've seen strtotime("2013-02-25 14:00:00 CST") on php.net, so would adding the time zone at the end be the way to go?

Comment: I use PHP's DateTime API. Just be careful though, if you pass a unix timestamp the result assumes UTC, so you have to make an extra call to `setTimezone` as demonstrated in the user comments (posted by Joel). Check it out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php. If you are passing in DateTime strings, you should be able to follow the examples posted in 'example 2'

Comment: Actually a follow-up question: If I want to save the current local time, then I'd use the user's timezone and code like this to create local time and then convert it to UTC, correct? `$myTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')); $myTime->setTimezone('UTC');` According to my tests, this shows me the local time first and then converts it, so I save that result to MySQL and use the same principle later to convert it back to local time. Correct?

Comment: Where are you getting now? It should be time(). And if php is configured to use UTC as the current timezone, then theoretically you just pass time() via the constructor, then set `$myTime->setTimezone('America/Chicago')`. But remember we do not want to consider timezones when saving data to mysql, only when rendering timezone to the user, based on the timezone they wish to use.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make this clear - not time, but time stamp or date+time. But I think the principle still applies: Use date() and strtotime() as usual as long as PHP's default timezone is UTC. Save this to MySQL. Use setTimezone ONLY when displaying time. Correct? Just making sure I got this :-) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `ONLY when displaying time` is the magic that will keep you from pulling your hair out down the road.

Comment: OK, I think I finally understood it all :-) Thanks again so much for your help and insight!